# Is there a difference or way to pick between Hosted Agents machine names 'fv-az532-*' and 'WIN-*'?

Tags: azure-devops, build-agent

In my build pipeline I'm noticing that Azure DevOps assigns one of two types of Hosted Agents for the 'windows-latest' image

Agent machine name: 'fv-az532-916'
Agent machine name: 'WIN-FU0AG5PCJKT'

When assigned the former type of agent, I get errors like running out of space or starting NuGet commands.

I've checked the sources and they shouldn't exceed 10gb. It runs fine on the other type of agent too. Is there any known difference between these two agents or any way to choose one?